# 16A current on an 10A power socket

Tags: power-supply, current, socket

## Issue

I am trying to power something that requires 16A of current using 3 different power supplies.

## Background

- I am not sure how much current my power socket can output or how I might go about checking this.
- I am assuming for now that it is only 10A just to be safe.
- I am wondering if there is any way that I can power this thing that requires 16A of current.

## Possible solution

In the instructions it says:

> if operating at home, please **power it via two sockets located on separate power rails**

I am not exactly sure what this means or if I even have two separate power rails. Could someone please explain to me how I might go about using two separate power rails?

Thank you!

Comment: Need more detail. For starters: What is it?

Comment: This sounds sketchy.  Does it have two separate power cords?  This is not normal, and potentially unsafe.  It is common in server computers to have two or more power supplies connected to multiple circuits for redundancy, but then you want each one to be able to handle the full load in case one breaker flips.  Combining outlets to increase current capacity is at the very least uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your profile idicates you are in Seattle WA, so I would assume your AC outlets are protected by 15 Amp circuit breakers, so you should restrict the load on any one circuit to 12 Amps.

You should therefore, plug your device into two independent (not fed from the same breaker) outlets.

Comment: Modern code in the US actually exclusively uses 20 breakers and wiring (AWG 12) for standard outlet circuits.  15 amp circuits (AWG 14) are only used for lighting or other fixed loads, or maybe if a circuit feeds only a single outlet.  The standard NEMA 5-15 outlet is still a 15 amp outlet, and older wiring may use true 15 amp circuits.

Comment: Not even clear that it is AC, though. The terminology is "power rails." A strange terminology if one is describing mains AC outlets, in my opinion.

Comment: @Evan: Thanks - I'm in Canada, and I think 15 amp circuits are common here for outlets.  If the OP's outlets are fed from 20 amp breakers, he is probably safe using a single circuit, provided there are no other significant loads on it.

Comment: So I looked at all the breakers, and I have 6 50 amp ones, a bunch of 20 amp ones and 4 15 amp ones. I am going to make sure nothing else is on one of the 50s and then put it there.

Comment: @pudility: the 50 Amp circuits are likely to be 240 volt, for electric stove, and probably electric heating - I can't think of any other reason for a 50 A circuit.  These circuits likely won't have a readily-accessible outlet. (if in a workshop, one may be an outlet for a welder.)

Comment: Yeah, the only output I could find was my water heater and tesla charger. I am trying out the 20amp one now.

Comment: Yeah, higher current circuits have special outlets, you won't find a 50 amp breaker feeding a standard outlet, that would be a gross code violation.